# Is there a test or function to perform multiple comparisons for a big dataset?

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, genetics

I have a big dataset of 2304 values : 384 different genes expression values in triplicates and for 2 different groups (ie, different treatments). I only want to compare the same genes between the 2 groups: e.g., gene A-treated vs gene A-control, and so on... and get the p values. I am NOT trying to compare different genes!

So I am running this command :

```r
data2 %>%
group_by(group) %>%
wilcox_test(expression ~ gene) %>%
adjust_pvalue(method = "BH") %>%
add_significance()
```

However, it is taking a lifetime to run on R so I am looking for a better function for this specific issue?

Comment: Statistics for genomics highly depends on the method used to produce your data

Comment: This demonstrates the error of running an experiment before having the analysis specified and vetted by a statistical consultant. It’s off topic really for SO but perhaps you could get a moderator to migrate the Q to the Bioinformatics forum.

Comment: Very helpful thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used a GLM that fits my data distribution and considers several factors instead of using a Wilcoxon test.